# Remove 2D points from rtree in Python

Tags: python, r-tree

I'm trying to store 2D points in an rtree (ver. 0.8.2) and then delete them using Python. I understand that rtree works with rectangles (or boxes in 3D), but I guess points are a subset of rectangles.

I'm getting strange behavior while deleting items from the rtree. The script below shows the behavior:

```py
from rtree import index as rtindex

def pt2rect(pt):
    return pt[0], pt[1], pt[0], pt[1]

pts = [(0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0), (0.0, 1.0)]
rt = rtindex.Index()

# Add the points
[rt.add(0, pt2rect(pt)) for pt in pts]
print [r.bbox for r in list(rt.nearest((0, 0), 10, True))]

# Remove the same points
for pt in pts:
    rt.delete(0, pt2rect(pt))
    print pt2rect(pt), [r.bbox for r in list(rt.nearest((0, 0), 10, True))]
```

And the output is:

```py
True
[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  # Whole index
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0) [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  # <-- Ok
(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  # <-- Wrong point deleted!
(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) [[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]]  # <-- Ok, as it's not found.
```

From the docs (http://toblerity.org/rtree/class.html):

> **delete**(id, coordinates) Deletes items from the index with the given
>   'id' within the specified coordinates.
>
> Parameters:
>
> **id** – long integer A long integer that is the identifier for this index
>   entry. IDs need not be unique to be inserted into the index, and it is
>   up to the user to ensure they are unique if this is a requirement.
>
> **coordinates** – sequence or array Dimension * 2 coordinate pairs,
>   representing the min and max coordinates in each dimension of the item
>   to be deleted from the index. Their ordering will depend on the
>   index’s interleaved data member. These are not the coordinates of a
>   space containing the item, but those of the item itself. Together with
>   the id parameter, they determine which item will be deleted. This may
>   be an object that satisfies the numpy array protocol.

But as can be seen, a point with the given `id` but NOT within the given coordinates is being deleted in line 4 of the output.

The documentation also clearly specifies that `id`s are not required to be unique in either insertion or deletion. (The repeated `0 == id` in the example is on purpose as I my application I need the duplicate `id`s. Multiple points for the same "thing".)

Also confirmed that points can be indexed by using `xmin == xmax` and `ymin == ymax`.

Am I using the library wrong, or is libspatialindex (the binary library behind Python rtree) behaving different to what the rtree docs state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't assign duplicate `id` to different objects.

It's deleting the **first object with matching `id`** it finds in the leaf (check the libspatialindex source code, `Leaf::deleteData` if you don't trust me). **Coordinates are only used to find the *correct* leaf to delete from**. All your `id`s are `0`, so it always deletes the first element from the leaf. The later deletions fail, because the bounding box of your tree is now `[0.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]`, and the points with y=0.0 cannot be in this leaf.

Try

```
[rt.add(id, [x[0], x[1], x[0], x[1]]) for id, x in enumerate(pts)]
```

and

```
for id, x in enumerate(pts):
    rt.delete(id, [x[0], x[1], x[0], x[1]])
    print [x.bbox for x in list(rt.nearest([0, 0], 10, True))]
```

Note that the **documentation of the rtree module is misleading**.

> Deletes items from the index with the given 'id' within the specified coordinates.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - id – long integer A long integer that is the identifier for this index entry. IDs need not be unique to be **inserted** into the index, and it is up to the user to ensure they are unique if this is a requirement.
> - coordinates – sequence or array Dimension * 2 coordinate pairs, representing the min and max coordinates in each dimension of the item to be deleted from the index. Their ordering will depend on the index’s interleaved data member. These are not the coordinates of a space containing the item, but those of the item itself. Together with the id parameter, they **determine** which item will be deleted. This may be an object that satisfies the numpy array protocol.

(Emphasis added.)

This does *not* say that the `id` is not required to be unique for *deletion*. It says you can insert multiple entries with the same `id`, but it doesn't say deletion will be predictable. ;-) Also "determine" is vague. The coordinates are used to find the correct leaf, then the first matching `id` in this leaf is deleted. (Judging from the source code of libspatialindex) Thus, **the `id` must be unique for deletion to work reliably**.

Comment: Your answer does not explain the observed behavior and is not presenting any reasoning behind the explanation.

Comment: Sure it does. You always delete the first object this way. Try using different `id`s, and it will work. Deletion doesn't check coordinates, it uses the coordinates to locate the correct *leaf node*, then deletes the first matching `id` within this leaf.

Comment: The common id is used on purpose because the points being added all belong to the same object, which is under one index in a list. If this is not possible, could you explain why or point at some reference? And, if you look at the output, sometimes the expected rectangle is not deleted and on others, the wrong rectangle is deleted or nothing is. What's going on?

Comment: You said "Don't assign duplicate id to different objects.", while the docs say: "IDs need not be unique to be inserted into the index."

Comment: Then you say: "Deletion doesn't check coordinates...", but docs say "These are not the coordinates of a space containing the item, but those of the item itself. Together with the id parameter, they determine which item will be deleted." So NOT the first object with matching `id`. The coordinates must match exactly as well as the `id`.

Comment: They don't need to be unique for *insertion*, but for deletion it doesn't give such guarantees... and no, it only says that the coordinates aren't *ignored* - they are used for finding the appropriate leaf. But within the leaf, the id is used as id...

Comment: Deletion in `Leaf::deleteData` (use the source, luke) only uses the `id`. The later deletions did not delete, because the leaf bounding box doesn't contain your coordinates anymore; and thus the leaf is not considered. But apparently, you don't want to receive assistance ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67777/discussion-between-jpcgt-and-anony-mousse).