# How to save Trajectories into a R-tree and how to set up its bounding boxes based on a b/w image

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, spatial, r-tree

I am currently looking for a way to save my trajectory data to any spatial index structure. I have "indoor maps" as .png files in black and white and apply the Djikstra shortest path algorithm on it, in order to create many trajectories all over the map. I do that like 1000 times with random start and end point. Black pixels are considered as obstacles and the paths go around them. The resulting Trajectories that i save in a pandas file with the columns `x y id frequency` should be somehow saved into for example an `r-tree`so that i can query my data easier later one. Unfortunately I do not find any code example for such a case and as I am very new to programming I do not know how to start. First step might be to define the `minimum-bounding-boxes` on my .png foto? I would really appreciate your help.

Example pandas table (x y coodinates represent pixels on the foto, id is the id of a path):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4], 
                'x':[1,1,1,1,1,5,4,4,10,10,9], 
                'y':[4,5,6,1,2,4,4,3,1,2,2],
                'frequency':[9,9,9,7,7,3,3,3,1,1,1]})
```

Here a foto of a output so you have an imagination of how it looks like:
[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

An r-tree *approximates* spatial objects such as trajectories with their bounding box. I doubt the bounding boxes will help you much (nor will the tree work well when they cover almost the entire data space). You'd probably need at least a few thousand objects for this to yield any benefit.

It may be better to index the trajectories via their start and end points as 4d vectors, for example, and then figure out what a good way to query that data is.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I run over your answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27660298/remove-2d-points-from-rtree-in-python just that morning. I want to use the r-tree for a route planning algorithm. As i also have to handle the interpolation of the starting point to a trajectory, I don't know if your 4D idea will suit my requirements. It should be also able to leave a trajectory in mid-way and take another from that point on. I still don't know if r-tree is a good choice but I am new to partial indexing and kind of lost

Comment: Well let us say I would try to do it the normal way  and save the trajectories not all points. How would I define the bounding boxes of a given set of trajectories over this map?

Comment: Bounding boxes are a well defined concept. You don't get to redefine them.

Comment: You seem to know a lot about the r-tree implementation. I would be very glad if you could have a look at this  [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679447/r-tree-intersection-function-does-not-find-a-point-even-though-it-should)

Comment: This is true, however @Mauritius could store segments of trajectories (or at least bounding boxes of segments) together with trajectory ID in the r-tree, not the bounding boxes representing the trajectories.